# What happened to Clay Liftoff?

Tags: soft-question, career

I noticed the other day that the Clay Liftoff program has been suspended. You can see this at http://www.claymath.org/fas/liftoff/. It also appears that there were fewer Fellows this year then in past years. There were 7 in 2009 compared to 18 in 2007. Are there financial issues at Clay?

Comment: This is quite off-topic...

Comment: Mariano, I concur.

Comment: Seems like something better discussed on a forum or a blog (or in a pub)

Comment: If someone at my pub (or department) knew the answer, I wouldn't have posted the question here! Is there a particular forum or blog you have in mind where this would be answered?

Comment: I agree that there isn't really a place on the web for math gossip; the best you can do is bring it up at a not completely inappropriate time in a comment thread on one of the popular blogs. Such a question doesn't belong very well on math blogs/forums, but it belongs *even more poorly* here. MO is a terrible framework for having a discussion (see also http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/21).